# Java how to create several jlists at runtime

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jlist

I need to create some tabbedpane called "menu" and in each of them I need to put a Jlist (product) with some other data extracted from a mysql db. I created this method but unfortunately it shows only the last jlist, the others menu tabbedpane are empty. Why? Thanks.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < menuLista.size(); i++) {
        int menuId = menuLista.get(i).getMenuId();
        jProductList = new JList(modelProductList);
        prodottiLista.clear();
        modelProductList.clear(); 
        prodottiLista = DBManager.fillProductList(menuId);

        for (int b = 0; b < prodottiLista.size(); b++) {
            modelProductList.addElement((Product) prodottiLista.get(b));
        }

        jProductList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jProductList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                jProductListValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        JPanel pL = new JPanel();
        pL.add(jScrollPane3);
        // panelList.add(pL);
        jTabbedPane1.addTab(menuLista.get(i).getMenuName(), pL);
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jProductList);
    }
```

I've modified the code like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < menuLista.size(); i++) {
        int menuId = menuLista.get(i).getMenuId();
        modelProductList.clear(); // ricarico la lista dei prodotti.
        prodottiLista = DBManager.fillProductList(menuId);

        for (int b = 0; b < prodottiLista.size(); b++) {
            modelProductList.addElement((Product) prodottiLista.get(b));
        }
        System.out.println(modelProductList);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jProductList);
        jTabbedPane1.addTab(menuLista.get(i).getMenuName(), scrollPane);

        jProductList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jProductList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                jProductListValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
    }
```

But It still doesn't work as I expected.

EDITED AGAIN:
I noticed that if I put this line:
System.out.println(modelProductList);
after that block of code, it prints exactly only the last products.
So, it's not a problem of visualization. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
jTabbedPane1.addTab(menuLista.get(i).getMenuName(), pL);
jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jProductList);
```

You add the last JList created to the viewport of the scroll pane. A viewport can only contain a single component.

I would guess you should be adding the tabbed pane to the viewport of the scroll pane. The tabbed pane should be added to the viewport outside of the loop, after all the tabs have been created.

Edit:

Sorry, I misread your code, I see you are adding the list to the scrollpane to a panel to the tabbed pane, so my suggestion is wrong.

However, I was close (I think?). I believe the problem is now with this line:

```
pL.add(jScrollPane3);
```

You only have a single instance of the scroll pane, so it can only be displayed on the last tab.

You need to create a new scroll pane for each tab. I would use code like the following:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( jProductList );
jTabbedPane1.addTab(menuLista.get(i).getMenuName(), scrollPane);
```

There is no need to add the scroll pane to the panel first. Now the scrollpane will resize as the size of the tabbed pane resizes.

Also, as a side not you should not be using instance variables in your for loop. Instead you should just be using local variables, since these variables will only exist to help you create the GUI objects you add to the tabbed pane.

For example, jProductList, prodottiLista, modelProductList, should all be local variables and you need to create a new instance of each class. You can't just clear() the contents from the model, because each JList will not have a reference to the same model, so again the data that you add to the last tab will be displayed on all tabs.

Comment: Did you mean:
jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTabbedPane1);
outsite the principal for loop?
I tried but I obtain an
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself

Comment: I tried like  you said but it doesn't work again, I put this line of code:
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( jProductList );
jTabbedPane1.addTab(menuLista.get(i).getMenuName(), scrollPane);
at the end of the first for loop. Maybe somewhere else? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've resolved. This is the working code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < menuLista.size(); i++) {
        int menuId = menuLista.get(i).getMenuId();
        DefaultListModel modelProductList = new DefaultListModel();
        JList jProductList = new JList(modelProductList);
        prodottiLista = DBManager.fillProductList(menuId);
        for (int b = 0; b < prodottiLista.size(); b++) {
            modelProductList.addElement((Product) prodottiLista.get(b));
        }
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jProductList);
        jTabbedPane1.addTab(menuLista.get(i).getMenuName(), scrollPane);
        jProductList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                jProductListValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jProductList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }
```